# Does ef core plus support batch update with minus?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-plus

I want to update stock quantity, such as +1, because so many requests do the same thing, and I don't want to lock the row for performance, then SQL which I wanted is :

```sql
Update Stock 
Set qty = qty + 1
where id = xxxx
```

Does Entity Framework Core Plus support it, or how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its obvious

```cs
db.Stock
  .Where(x => x.Id == id)
  .Update(x => new Stock { qty = x.qty + 1 });
```